# tslint: i want to force param typedef but allow inferred types

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings, tslint

In my tslint.json I have this:

```
"typedef": [true, "call-signature", "parameter"],
"no-inferrable-types": [true, "ignore-params"],
```

as I want to force functions to have a return type and params to have a type however this forces me to have type on inferred params. example:

This fails even though start and end are inferred as numbers:

```
transform(start = 6, end = 4): number {
    return;
}
```

Is there a way to force the params to have a type ONLY when they are not initialised like the example?

This should pass:

```
transform(start = 6, end = 4): number {
    return;
}
```

This should fail:

```
transform(start, end): number {
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old one.

Should you just remove `typedef` and enable `no-inferrable-types` without any parameters?

For the function return values, you can use `@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types`